# iOS AWS SNS: How does client confirm SNS Topic subscription?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

After a device registers for remote notifications (in *application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken*) I am:

1. Creating a platform endpoint using the device's token.
2. Subscribing to a topic.
3. Attempting* to confirm topic subscription

I am stuck on step 3 from the above list. I can't figure out how to get the token needed to create a "AWSSNSConfirmSubscriptionInput" object to pass to "confirmSubscription".

I should note that I am able to send APNs from the topic despite the fact that the subscription is not confirmed. Is this not a necessary step in the context of iOS (application protocol)?

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html) states following:

> To actually create a subscription, the endpoint owner must call the ConfirmSubscription action with the token from the confirmation message. Confirmation tokens are valid for three days.

I can't figure out how to obtain the "token" necessary to perform the "ConfirmSubscription" action. The "Subscribe" action result is of type "AWSSNSSubscribeResponse" which only has a single propery, " subscriptionArn" and does not appear to contain a "confirmation message" including a token. So how do I obtain this token?

Here is the body of my application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken delegate method:

```
sns.createPlatformEndpoint(createPlatformEndPointInput).continueWithBlock { (task:AWSTask!) in
        if let error = task.error{
            XCGLogger.defaultInstance().error("Platform endpoint creation error: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
        let result = task.result as! AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse
        let subscribeInput = AWSSNSSubscribeInput()
        subscribeInput.topicArn = "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxx:topicname"
        subscribeInput.endpoint = result.endpointArn
        subscribeInput.protocols = "application"
        sns.subscribe(subscribeInput).continueWithBlock({ (task:AWSTask!) in
            if let subError = task.error{
                XCGLogger.defaultInstance().error("Topic Subscription Error: \(subError)")
                return nil
            }
            let subscribeResult = task.result as! AWSSNSSubscribeResponse
            XCGLogger.defaultInstance().debug("Subscription result: \(subscribeResult)")
            let subscriptionConfirmInput = AWSSNSConfirmSubscriptionInput()
            subscriptionConfirmInput.token = ?? //How do I get this??
            subscriptionConfirmInput.topicArn = "arn:aws:sns:xxx:myTopic"
            sns.confirmSubscription(subscriptionConfirmInput).continueWithBlock({ (task:AWSTask!) in
                if let error = task.error{
                    XCGLogger.defaultInstance().error("Subscription Confirmation Error: \(error)")
                }
                return nil
            })
            return nil
        })
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Subscribe` returns `SubscriptionArn` if the service was able to create a subscription immediately (without requiring endpoint owner confirmation). For mobile devices, this should be the case.

As a side note, when registering the device, you should follow the pseudo code in this [blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx223MJB0XKV9RU/Mobile-token-management-with-Amazon-SNS). [AWS Mobile Hub](http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/) can produce a reference implementation for registering the device and subscribing to a topic using the recommended workflow as well.

Comment: In short... it's not necessary to confirm the subscription in this scenario. Thanks for posting the link.